# teradata select a specific range of months

Tags: timestamp, teradata

I have more than 5million of records that I need to split in two part 
where I used this

```
/*(cast(cast(cast(A.ORD_DTS as char(19)) as timestamp(0)) as date) >=
(add_months(current_date,-13))- extract(day from add_months(current_date,-13))+1) 
*/
```

How can select from '2015-03-31'  to '2014-09-01'  ?

```
--current_date,-13

--CURRENT_DAY=10/14/2015

 --09/01/2014 12:00:00.000000  --MIN --13 CURRENT

 --10/13/2015 4:00:06.000000   --MAX --13 CURRENT
```

---

I tried

```
cast(cast(cast(A.ORD_DTS as char(19)) as timestamp(0)) as date)
 BETWEEN CAST('2015-03-31' AS DATE ) AND CAST('2014-09-01' AS DATE )
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `ORD_DTS`, `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `CHAR`? And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: A.ORD_DTS is datetime  
'09/01/2014 12:00:00.000000'
---teradata version 14.00.04.17e

Comment: Then it's a simple: `WHERE A.ORD_DTS BETWEEN  DATE '2015-03-31'  AND  DATE '2014-09-01'`, when you compare `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` the timestamp is automatically casted to DATE

Comment: by trying 
 A.ORD_CRT_DTS  BETWEEN date '2015-03-31'  AND date '2014-09-01' 
I get 
>nothing <

Comment: I tried also 

SELECT top 1 CAST(TIMESTAMP A.ORD_CRT_DTS  AS DATE)

............

FAILED 

ERROR [42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the 'TIMESTAMP' keyword and the word 'A'.
SELECT Command Failed.

Comment: ` A.ORD_CRT_DTS BETWEEN date '2015-03-31' AND date '2014-09-01'` isn't going to ever return anything, try reversing the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out..didnt executed it but it should work.`Select * from table A where A.ORD_DTS >= DATE '2014-09-01' and A.ORD_DTS  <= DATE '2015-03-31'`

Comment: However dnoeth solution will also work ..but while specifying range you must use the lower limit first and then upper limit.

Select * from testt A where A.dte BETWEEN  '2015-03-31'  AND  '2014-09-01'  
-- zero rows

Select * from testt A where A.dte BETWEEN  '2014-09-01' AND   '2015-03-31'
-- 2 rows selected.

Comment: thanks ... I saw the mistake ... thanks you :)  anwaar_hell  and dnoeth !!